# Where are Proxy Settings Stored?

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

I'm coding a small application that connects to the Internet and retrieves information from my server using `bsd socket`. I looked at where the proxy settings are stored under Linux but i couldn't the file containing this information.

I just want to find that file, so I can read the proxy settings from it and use these settings in my application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're in the `$http_proxy`, `$https_proxy` and `$ftp_proxy` environment variables. Also, `$no_proxy` contains a comma-separated list of host patterns for which no proxy is used. For example:

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:3128/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,*.example.com
```

Comment: thanks, does this work on all linux desktops? or just gnome?

Comment: It's a de facto *nix standard.

Comment: @killercode There are applications that have their own settings, especially browsers that have a Javascript interpreter and support PAC files. But the default expectation is that a unix application will support at least these environment variables, and it's reasonable to tell your users to ensure the environment variables are set.